# Measurability and equality of functions on product measure space

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions, product-measure

Let $(\Omega_1,\mathcal{A}_1,\mu_1)$, $(\Omega_2,\mathcal{A}_2,\mu_2)$ be two finite measure spaces and denote by $(\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2,\mathcal{A}_1 \otimes \mathcal{A}_2,\mu_1 \otimes \mu_2)$ the product measure space. I would like to know if the following statement is true:

Let $f \in L_1(\mu_1 \otimes \mu_2)$ and $g:\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (not necassarily measurable!). If $f(x,\cdot) = g(x,\cdot)$ $\mu_2$-a.e. for $\mu_1$-a.e. $x \in \Omega_1$, then $g$ is $\mu_1 \otimes \mu_2$-measurable and the identity $f = g$ holds $\mu_1 \otimes \mu_2$-almost everywhere.

If this statement does not hold so generally, does it perhaps hold on more specific measure spaces, e.g., on open bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Could eventually someone help me out here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For a basic counter example : Let $\Omega _i=[0,1]$, $\mu_i$ being the Lebesgue measure and $\mathcal A_i$ the Borel $\sigma -$algebra. Let $\mathcal N\subset \Omega _2$ be a non-Borel set. Take $f=0$ and $g=\boldsymbol 1_{\mathcal N\times \{0\}}$. I think that the statement is true if $\mathcal A_1\otimes \mathcal A_2$ is complete... (but I'm not 100% sure)